# Is it allowed to run a single pair of wires in two separate conduits?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I am currently working on the wiring in a friend's house. When it was originally installed, the homeowners insisted that every wire be placed in its own conduit. This means that every power socket has two conduits running to it, and every light switch has three:

[image: light switch and socket]

[image: socket]

As you might imagine, this means that to run a new conduit to somewhere, you would need to spend twice the effort. This is really annoying, but this is a rule imposed by some older folks who don't believe in the fire-safety of double-insulated wires; they had a house fire multiple times, so one can forgive them a certain degree of paranoia.

I was wondering -- is this actually legal? Are you allowed to split a single double-insulated wire into two single-insulated wires and run them like this? If not, is there a clear reason why? If it is, are there any good reasons for why you might do this?

This is in Russia, so I would ideally want answers regarding the Russian electrical code, but I don't suppose there are many people familiar with that here so European standard-based answers are also acceptable.

Comment: In the US our code NEC or NFPA70 having the conductors in separate conduits would be a violation.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's legal (I have no idea if it is in Russia), it's definitely less safe to do it that way.  All electric currents put out magnetic fields, but a hot/neutral pair put out *opposite* magnetic fields, so they cancel each other out if you keep them close together.  If you leave them apart, then they create an inductor, and if there's any metal between them (a nail, for example), they can induce currents in it and heat it up.  This is why the US electrical code requires all hots be in the same cable or conduit as their corresponding neutral.

Comment: Are the raceways (conduit is round) and boxes plastic, some nonferrous metal (such as aluminum), or steel?   That matters *greatly* here

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel They are plastic, with steel wood screws attaching them to the wall. I guess I should edit the tag on the question then?

Comment: I would guess **nyet**.  It's not legal.  The wires have been manufactured and then _tested with the outer insulation_.  By splitting the wires, you don't know what you have or what tests they can pass.